# Prevent CSRF in Web Forms using Ajax and Web Api in the server side

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, csrf

I got a site where I need to avoid CSRF attacks. I have researched a lot of time and all examples use a function in the client side like this

```
@functions{
    public string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}
```

After an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax("api/values", {
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {  }, // JSON data goes here
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
    }
});
```

Obviously the first code is a MVC razor call, so I can't use it in my case. Is there a way to obtain this Anti-Forgery Tokens with javascript/jquery without using ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

In the aspx or ascx file, put an hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnAntiForgeryTokens" runat="server" value=""/>
```

In the C# side, create a property like this:

```
    protected string AntiForgeryTokens
    {
        get
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }
    }
```

And assign a value to it in the Page_Load event:

```
hdnAntiForgeryTokens.Value = AntiForgeryTokens;
```

After that, read the value using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: //your web api url,
        data: getJason(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            'RequestVerificationToken': $('#hdnAntiForgeryTokens').val()
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function _() {
                //success handling
            },
            500: function (){
                //error handling
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps to someone else who has this issue.